# Get List of DataKeyValues from RadGridView using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, telerik, radgrid

I'm using a Telerik RadGrid and have a GridTemplateColumn with the unique name "ChangeAddr". Basically, a user would check one or more boxes and then click a "Change Address" button so the user could change the address for the selected rows/products.

The checkbox id is chkChangeAddr.
The DataKeyName is OrderProductID.

Now, here's the code I have for when the user clicks the button:

```
var OrderProductIDs = (from GridDataItem item in rgShipProducts.Items
                               where ((CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkChangeAddr")).Checked
                               select int.Parse(rgShipProducts.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[item.ItemIndex]["OrderProductID"].ToString())).ToList();
```

However, it doesn't return anything.

If it helps, I have an event for OnItemDataBound where I can successfully retrieve the DataKeyValue using this same snippet:

```
rgShipProducts.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[item.DataSetIndex]["OrderProductID"].ToString()
```

So, it seems like I'm not "accessing" each item or something. I've done this with regular ListViews, but never on a RadGrid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Your first snippet has ItemIndex as its index, while the second has DataSetIndex. Is that significant?

Comment: I tried it with both variations and didn't get a different result. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with below code.

```
List<GridDataItem> Items = (from item in rgShipProducts.MasterTableView.Items.Cast<GridDataItem>()
                                where  ((CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkChangeAddr")).Checked
                                select item).ToList();

    if (Items.Count > 0)
    {
        string strkey = Items[0].GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
    }
```